# Raspberry Pi - Error accessing 0x40: Check your I2C address

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I try run this Python servo script on my Raspberry Pi. I got this code from here:

https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/blob/master/Adafruit_PWM_Servo_Driver/Servo_Example.py

Python servo script

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Adafruit_PWM_Servo_Driver import PWM
import time

# ===========================================================================
# Example Code
# ===========================================================================

# Initialise the PWM device using the default address
# bmp = PWM(0x40, debug=True)
pwm = PWM(0x40, debug=True)

servoMin = 150  # Min pulse length out of 4096
servoMax = 600  # Max pulse length out of 4096

def setServoPulse(channel, pulse):
  pulseLength = 1000000                   # 1,000,000 us per second
  pulseLength /= 60                       # 60 Hz
  print "%d us per period" % pulseLength
  pulseLength /= 4096                     # 12 bits of resolution
  print "%d us per bit" % pulseLength
  pulse *= 1000
  pulse /= pulseLength
  pwm.setPWM(channel, 0, pulse)

pwm.setPWMFreq(60)                        # Set frequency to 60 Hz
while (True):
  # Change speed of continuous servo on channel O
  pwm.setPWM(0, 0, servoMin)
  time.sleep(1)
  pwm.setPWM(0, 0, servoMax)
  time.sleep(1)
```

I try this solution but not helping.

https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-16-channel-servo-driver-with-raspberry-pi.pdf

[image]

[image]

What can I try next?

Comment: May be more suitable on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't want to be logged as root everytime: just put sudo when you need and type the password.

Second: your i2c bus is not properly configured or your wiring are wrong. **The command i2cdetect doesn't see anything attached**. 
You have installed smbus and i2ctools, but have you removed i2c-bcm2708 from blacklist?
You need to type:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf
```

and add a # to the line i2c-dev and i2c-bcm2708.

from:

```
blacklist i2c-dev
blacklist i2c-bcm2708
```

to:

```
#blacklist i2c-dev
#blacklist i2c-bcm2708
```

than you need to add the modules for i2c at startup

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

and add these two lines to the end of the file:

```
i2c-bcm2708 
i2c-dev
```

now you can manually load these modules with the commands

```
sudo modprobe i2c-bcm2708
sudo modprobe i2c-dev
```

now type again :

```
sudo i2cdetect -y 0 #if you have a rev1 board

sudo i2cdetect -y 1 #if you have a rev2 board
```

Now, if you see anything but dots in the chart (like before), check for your wiring.
If you see something, that's the address of the servo driver.